# how add a dropdownlist to my MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

HELP:
i would like to add a dropdownlist to my MVC3 application using code first and c#.
i have 2 table Student and University, i need to put a dynamic list of university in a Create view of Student.
how and where should be add methode to my controller.
some one help me please
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are getting down votes because you could have just googled this and easily found the answer.  Anyways, here's a link to get you started.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is you pass the drop down list as a property of the class that send to the view.
So something like this:

```
public Student
{
public List<University> Universities({//get list from database in getter
```

Then in the the view use something like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StudentsSchool, Model.Universities)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create Entity class for your dropdown. It will return a list of value

```
public class KeyValueEntity
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

public class MyViewModel
    {
        public List<KeyValueEntity> Status { get; set; }
}
```

On your controller write the following code

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Dropdown()
        {  
                MyViewModel model = GetDefaultModel();  
                return View(model);
            }
        }


public MyViewModel GetDefaultModel()
        {
            var entity = new MyViewModel();            
            entity.Status = GetMyDropdownValues();            
            return entity;
        }


private List<KeyValueEntity> GetMyDropdownValues()
        {
            return new List<KeyValueEntity>
            {
                new KeyValueEntity { Description = "Yes" , Value ="1" },
                new KeyValueEntity { Description = "No" , Value ="0"}
            };
        }
```

Code for your cshtml page :
Now you need to bind your view with your model for this on top of your view you define your model class

```
@model MyViewModel
Following is the code for dropdown binding

 @Html.LabelForModel("Status:")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, new SelectList(Model.Status, "Value", "Description"), "-- Please Select --")
```